# How get result?

Tags: android, kotlin

I trying to get result when  i add values EditText . How i can do it and show result , because i dont understand

```kotlin
class CheckSkillsFragment : MainActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCheckSkillBinding
    private lateinit var parameter1: EditText
    private lateinit var skill1: EditText
    private lateinit var modifier1: EditText
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_check_skill)
        binding = FragmentCheckSkillBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        initViews()

        binding.sumCreatureButton.setOnClickListener {
            result()
        }
    }

    private fun initViews() {
        parameter1 = findViewById(R.id.parameter_first_player_editText)
        skill1 = findViewById(R.id.skill_first_player_editText)
        modifier1 = findViewById(R.id.modifier_first_player_edit_text)
    }

    private fun conviert() {
        var valueX = parameter1.toString().toInt()
        var y = skill1.toString().toInt()
        var z = modifier1.toString().toInt()
        var c = (0..6).random()
        result(valueX, y, z, c)
    }

    private fun result(valueX: Int, y: Int, z: Int, c: Int) {
        var result1 = (valueX + y + z + c).toString()
        Toast.makeText(this, result1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a mix of `viewBinding` and old `findViewById`. I would suggest to use only one of them: either keep using `binding` (suggested), or remove it

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `binding`, you don't need to declare `EditTexts` as well as you are defining two `setContentViews`, you just need one with `binding.root`. Also, you are inheriting it from `MainActivity` but it should be from `AppCompactActivity` and instead of calling `result` directly, you should call `conviert` in `onClickListener`. Like this:

```
class CheckSkillsFragment : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCheckSkillBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentCheckSkillBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.sumCreatureButton.setOnClickListener {
            conviert()
        }
    }

    private fun conviert() {

        var valueX = binding.parameterFirstPlayerEditText.text.toString().toInt()
        var y = binding.skillFirstPlayerEditText.text.toString().toInt()
        var z = binding.modifierFirstPlayerEditText.text.toString().toInt()
        var c = (0..6).random()
        result(valueX, y, z, c)
    }

    private fun result(valueX: Int, y: Int, z: Int, c: Int) {

        var result1 = (valueX + y + z + c).toString()
        Toast.makeText(this, result1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
}
```